# Enable TypeScript to find files in VSCode that don't have default export

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

The goal is to enable the `Quick Fix` functionality for all files when receiving the error `Cannot find name 'myUtil'.ts(2304)`

TypeScript is great at finding my files that `export default MyComponent` and use the filename `MyComponent.tsx`, but when using a file that only has `export const myFunction = () => {}` inside the filename `utils/my-util.ts`,  the `Quick Fix` doesn't appear for this code:

```
myUtil.myFunction()
```

Instead, it just shows the error below without the `Quick Fix` option:

```
Cannot find name 'myUtil'.ts(2304)
```

Normally, `Quick Fix` will add

```
import MyComponent from 'components/MyComponent'
```

but it doesn't seem to work when you need

```
import * as myUtil from 'utils/my-util'
```

How can you configure TypeScript in VSCode to enable quick fix for files that don't have a default export and aren't named the same as they are imported? Would this require changing files to be named exactly the same as they're named - eg. `utils/myUtil` - and/or export a default object containing all of the exports instead of exporting them individually?

Comment: I tried in VSC, and when I typed `myFunc`, it showed an option `myFunction` in intellisense. After selecting it, it was automatically added to imports.

Comment: Yes, that works, but it doesn't do the `import *`, only `import { myFunction }`

Comment: How would it know to map your variable name to an arbitrary file?

Comment: Because it's a named export. Maybe the real question is should files be exporting members using a naming convention that requires them to be called under another namespace (ie. invoking via `myUtil.myFunction` vs `myFunction`). In my experience working on larger codebases, namespacing is essential for organization, but `export default { myFunction, ... }` gets very messy, so it's easier to just `export function myFunction() {}`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way of doing this would be to create a default export around your functions, e.g.:

```
export default const myUtils {
    foo() {},
    bar() {}
}
```

Or by importing the functions and using them directly, e.g.:

```
import { bar } from 'utils/my-util'
```

If you then use foo, the `Quick Fix` should say something like "add missing foo to utils/my-util import statement".

Using `import <something> as <somethingElse> from` let's you change the name of your import in your file. You use `import * as <something>` when your import has no name. `Quick Fix` can't decide what name to give an import that has no name.
Or you have a named default export and VSCode knows what to name your import, or you don't and you have to give it a name yourself when importing.

So my answer is, I don't think it is possible and I'm pretty sure it doesn't take your filenames into consideration.